# Python class inclusion wrong behaviour

Tags: python

I have into my main.py

```
from modules import controller
ctrl = controller
help(ctrl)
print(ctrl.div(5,2))
```

and the controllor.py is:

```
class controller:
    def div(self, x, y): 
        return x // y
```

when I run my main I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\main.py", line 8, in ?
    print(ctrl.div(5,2))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'div'
```

WHat is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute following code

```
from modules import controller
ctrl = controller
```

**ctrl** variable becomes a pointer to **controller** class.
To create an instance of **controller** class you need to add parenthesis:

```
from modules import controller
ctrl = controller()
```

Answer (score 4):

This is very confusing as shown.

When you say

```
from modules import controller
```

You're making the claim that you have a module with a filename of `modules.py`.

OR

You're making the claim that you have a package named `modules`.  This directory has an `__init__.py` file and a module with a filename of `controller.py`

You should clarify this to be precise.  It looks like you have mis-named your files and modules in the the example code posted here.

When you say

```
from modules import controller
```

That creates a *module* (not a class) named `controller`.

When you say

```
ctrl = controller
```

That creates another name for the `controller` *module*, `ctrl`.

At no time to you reference the class (`controller.controller`).  At no time did you create an instance of the class (`controller.controller()`).

Answer (score 3):

> ctrl = controller

‘controller’ is a module, representing your whole ‘controller.py’ file. In Python, unlike in Java, there can be any number of symbols defined inside a module, so there isn't a 1:1 relationship between the imported module and the class defined in it.

So the script complains because the ‘controller’ module does not have a ‘div’ function; ‘div’ is defined as a method of the ‘controller’ class *inside* the ‘controller’ module. If you want an instance of the controller() class you need to say:

```
ctrl= controller.controller()
```

(Note also the () to instantiate the object, or you'll be getting the class itself rather than an instance. If you do really want to define a static method in the class so you can call it without an instance, you can do this using the ‘staticmethod’ decorator and omitting ‘self’.)

It's usually best to name your classes with an initial capital to avoid confusion:

```
class Controller(object):
    ...

ctrl= controller.Controller()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create an instance of controller, like this:

```
ctrl = controller()
```

Note the brackets after controller.